# How to get html tag attribute with square brackets using css selector?

Tags: html, parsing, scrapy, css-selectors, html-parsing

So I want to parse one page and it has several items with following structure:

```
<span itemprop="telephone" [class]="revealtel?'':'invisible'" class="">11111111</span>
<span itemprop="telephone" [class]="revealmainfax?'':'invisible'" class="">222222222</span>
```

I am using Scrapy and CSS selectors to parse data. But I cannot understand how to get tel or fax numbers. Itemprop is the same in both cases, so it cannot be used. So, how to select element with `[class]="revealtel?'':'invisible'` or `[class]="revealmainfax?'':'invisible'` attributes?
Maybe not using CSS Selectors, but Xpath? I am not strong with Xpaths though...

Thanks in advance for helping me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using xpath to get a list of all text from elements with `telephone` as itemprop.

```
faxnum = None
telnum = None
numbers = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="telephone"]')
for element in numbers:
    text = element.extract()
    if re.search('revealmainfax', text):
        faxnum = element.xpath('./text()')
    else:
        telnum = element.xpath('./text()')
```

Comment: the problem is to separate fax numbers (```revealmainfax```) from phone numbers(```revealtel```). To extract all numbers at a time I can use css selector ```response.css("span[itemprop='telephone']::text").extract()```

Comment: @Artsiom  Neither xpath nor css is going to help you in this situation because `[class]` is not a valid html attribute name with the square brackets.  You should probably use regex to determine which element is fax and which is tel or regular string searching.  I showed an example in my answer but I haven't tested it so it might need some adjusting

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
response.css('span[itemprop="telephone"]::text').getall()
```